# Java Packager Tool : custom install location

Tags: java, deployment, ant, javafx, packaging

I'm working around "Self-Contained Application" generation using [Java Packager Tool](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/part_packaging.html). By default, the '.exe' bundle is installed under "C:\Program Files (x86)" but I would like install it to a custom location : "C:\MyApp" for example.

To generate my bundle, I'm using an Ant Task inside a Maven build :

```
<target xmlns:fx="javafx:com.sun.javafx.tools.ant">

    <property name="jre.dir" value="${env.JAVA_HOME}/jre" />
    <property name="version" value="0.0.3" />

    <taskdef resource="com/sun/javafx/tools/ant/antlib.xml"
        uri="javafx:com.sun.javafx.tools.ant" classpath="${env.JAVA_HOME}/lib/ant-javafx.jar" />

    <echo message="// ----------------------------------- //" />
    <echo message="//     START JAVAPACKAGER ANT TASK     //" />
    <echo message="// ----------------------------------- //" />

    <fx:deploy nativeBundles="exe" outdir="${basedir}/packager"
        outfile="MyApp_${version}">

        <fx:application name="MyApp" mainClass="com.myfirm.myapp.bootstrap.BootstrapMain">
            <fx:argument>-bundlesDir=./bundles/</fx:argument>
        </fx:application>

        <fx:resources>
            <fx:fileset dir="${project.basedir}/target"
                includes="${project.name}-${project.version}-jar-with-dependencies.jar" />
            <fx:fileset dir="${project.basedir}" includes="bundles/*.jar" />
        </fx:resources>

        <fx:info title="MyApp ${version}" vendor="MyFirm">
            <fx:icon href="${project.basedir}/myapp.ico" kind="default" width="32" height="32" depth="8" />
        </fx:info>

        <fx:preferences install="true" shortcut="true" />

        <fx:platform basedir="${jre.dir}"/>   

    </fx:deploy>
</target>
```

Has anybody work around this ? And could tell me more about how to configure more precisely the generated native bundle ?

Thanks by advance.

**EDIT**

Under Windows, I have found a way to do it : by editing file *com\oracle\tools\packager\windows\template.iss* in jar %JAVA_HOME%\lib\ant-javafx.jar. But this solution seems to be ugly and not portable ! So I'm now looking for a way to override it in my ant task...

Comment: The installers installation directory depends on INNO/WIX setup for Windows.

Comment: @ItachiUchiha Yes I know about INNO/WIX, but none of them allow to specify custom installers installation directory as I can see [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/self-contained-packaging.html), Table 7-2

Comment: You may want to go through [WIX Documentation for custom path](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/wixui/dialog_reference/wixui_installdir.html). If you are using Inno, it has a similar feature.

Comment: @ItachiUchiha Ok, but where can I override it from my build script ??

Comment: You can't you need to write your own script and execute it while using the custom packager in your build file.

Comment: I see, but doing that I loose the portability of my script...

Comment: To overcome the scenario, you could package the Wix/Inno along with the project.

Comment: To @thibault, and any other passers-by, you *dont* have to edit the JDK. Simply take the template and use it as a drop-in resource. The javapackager will still inject your version number and all that. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54027883/5432315) for full details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For extra documentation, what Tib Us did was edit %JAVA_HOME%\lib\ant-javafx.jar.  You can use [7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) (or others) to open that jar file and update it's contents.

---

In com\oracle\tools\packager\windows\template.iss, change this line:

```
DefaultDirName=APPLICATION_INSTALL_ROOT\APPLICATION_NAME
```

To:

```
DefaultDirName={pf}\APPLICATION_NAME
```

`{pf}` is a Inno Setup constant pointing to 32-bit or 64-bit Program Files folder.  See [Inno Setup Help](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=consts).

---

If you'd like to install in Program Files, then it is helpful to change:

```
PrivilegesRequired=APPLICATION_INSTALL_PRIVILEGE
```

To:

```
PrivilegesRequired=admin
```

Also, if your program is going to be used by non-admin users and will be writing to its folder in Program Files, then you'll need some [special folder permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28531684/132374).  Here is some [background on permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8424542/132374) for an app running in Program Files.

---

You might also like to add this, to ensure that the new install location is used:

```
UsePreviousAppDir=No
```

---

This solution isn't ideal, but is better than nothing.

Comment: Editing the JDK isn't necessary to accomplish your goal. Just take that [template file](https://gist.github.com/TurekBot/8aa610bcd6695a6b5e7722bd4111a7f5) and use it as a [drop-in resource](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/self-contained-packaging.html#BCGICFDB). The javapackager will still replace all the UPPER_WITH_UNDERSCORE variables.

Answer (score 2):

Getting the template from the jar file is fine—or [download it here](https://gist.github.com/TurekBot/8aa610bcd6695a6b5e7722bd4111a7f5)—but you *don't* need to edit it where it is.

Once you have that template, you can just use it as a [drop-in resource](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/self-contained-packaging.html#BCGICFDB). All the variables that look like `SOME_VARIABLE`, that is, upper case and which use underscores, will still be replaced by the [javapackager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/packager.html#CCHIHIIJ).

This solution is much more portable because it doesn't involve editing the JDK; just include your template in `package/windows/` as `YourAppName.iss`.

Comment: 4 years later, this comment was a saviour. To add, the following additions to the Java 9 docs added the extra step I need to work in a modular system. https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8186683?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Aall-tabpanel

Answer (score -1):

User Option -BinstalldirChooser=true